# How do I make a diagonal grid/flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid, skew

[Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csYa5.png)

So I want to make an item container which looks like this in the picture.
I started with creating an .grid-container, then going on with divs inside the container with .grid-item & .item1. 
`<div class="grid-container">`
`<div class="grid-item item1></div>`
`</div>`

for .css I had the idea for skew(-12.5deg)
`.grid-container{`
`transform: skew(-12.5deg);`
`}`

`.grid-item{`
`transform: skew(12.5deg); //unskew`
`}`

`.item1{`
`background-image:url(item1.jpg);`
`}`

Sadly the items won't unskew... They just rotate the image inside the item, but I want them to stay straight, just the "border/layout" should be skewed.

Also the grid won't let me place the items in one line, they just make another line... Maybe switch to flexbox?

Comment: This page explains everything about diagonal layouts, perhaps it could help you https://9elements.com/blog/pure-css-diagonal-layouts/

Comment: grid requires a `grid-template-columns`  to be set else to draw columns, defaut value is 1fr, so it will be a single column. You should share enough of your code to reproduce your issue. Minimal HTML & CSS . doing so, you may find yourself why it went wrong ;) , if not we can see what you really have and help from there.